# passive/active sql injection Does this classification exist?

Tags: sql, sql-injection

Perhaps it may sound strange but I was told that SQL injection attacks 
can be classified as:

> `passive and active`

**Passive** SQLi:

- it is related to SQL statement such: 
  `SELECT,UNION,GROUP BY,LOAD,HAVING EXECUTE, BEGIN, DECLARE`...etc

**Active** SQLi:

- it is supposed to be more dangerous since it involves modifying the DBMS through statements like: `UPDATE,DELETE,INSERT` ..etc so

I haven't yet found anything about it in terms of white papers, study material and so on.

Comment: you said it. it can be classified, but there's no harm with using different terminologies for the same classifications. But what are you looking for exactly??

Comment: As far as I understand it, passive means it looks at your data, active means it alters your data.  But exactly the same tactics are used, and it doesn't seem a very useful classification.

Comment: That's exactly what you said..Read and alter...I just wanted to find an article or whatever mentioning that as a way of getting a reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OWASP defines passive and active sql injections [here](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Testing_Guide_Appendix_C%3a_Fuzz_Vectors#SQL_Injection)

> SQL Injection is classified in the following two categories, depending
>   on the exposure of database information (passive) or the alteration of
>   database information (active).

Both are problematic, and if you have one you probably have the other. The problem with active is fairly obvious (someone is updating/creating/deleting your data in ways you didn't plan). Passive is just as dangerous though for you and your users though. Imagine if they get a list of usernames and passwords. These could be used to login legitamently to your website, or to other websites as most users reuse passwords on multiple sites.

Answer (score 1):

SQL injection is simply adding undesired text to your queries.
You can group it as you wish, but it doesn't really matter, the simple thing is, your query doesn't do what you want or does not  only what you want.

Comment: Not sure this question deserves an answer.

Comment: I've retracted my downvote though...  Can't blame you for the fact that I just quit smoking!

Comment: @DonRoby, Yeah see my prev comment. :) let's delete our off-topic comments. Good luck with smoking!!!

Answer (score 0):

I've never heard of sql injection attacks being broken down into categories.  As gdoron so eloquently put it, it doesn't matter.

However, looking at how you broke it down it almost makes sense.  I'd change that classification slightly to be:

**Passive**:
Attack involving overriding the expected input in such a way as to bypass normal security controls.  For example, let's say you have a page with a query string such as:

```
/accounts/edit.php?id=50
```

In this case, manually changing the id to 1 or 10 could potentially pull up a record the user does not have access to.  Provided that the edit page doesn't perform additional checks to ensure the user has access.

**Active**:
Attack whereby sql statements are passed into input fields in order to cause the application to execute the new statement.

For example, putting [' or (1=1);drop table users;'](http://xkcd.com/327/) into a login field.  Some applications simply concatenate sql with unsanitized user input.  This could allow an attacker to bypass security controls or even send DDL statements to the database server.

Comment: would your definition of passive attack be classed as SQL injection? You're not really getting sql to do something that was unexpected, you're just not checking security properly. It's an authorisation problem, not a SQL injection

Comment: Per OSWASP it depends upon the "exposure" of the database.  In the first one you aren't changing the SQL, just bypassing any type of code controls to get to data you probably shouldn't be able to see... But I see that you already answered that. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't say that SQL injection involving DELETE is necessarily "worse" than SQL injection involving SELECT.  It's true one can modify data and the other doesn't.

But a lot of scary SQL injection is perpetrated solely to read data that is supposed to be restricted, e.g. stealing [credit card numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albert_Gonzalez).

Usually the terminology around SQL injection has to do with the methods of attack, such as "blind SQL injection," "union-based SQL injection," etc.

If you want to read a mighty book that covers the subject very well, try [SQL Injection Attacks and Defense](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1597499633) by Justin Clarke et. al.

Answer (score 0):

Because SQL Injection is a technique used to **ATTACK** a website, wether it is passive or active is of inconsequence as many of the others members have said already.

No the TERMS you use in the first paragraph are PASSIVE is incorrect,
Execute is not passive, its active... its Executing (something or other)

And even a passive term such as SELECT when used with DropTable can cause you to lose data too!
So you would still insist on calling it passive?
When its ACTIVELY dropping a table?

A good source of further information is wikipedia.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: If you had drop then it would become an active statement. Check out OWASP for definitions (see my answer for link). Passive is still dangerous though and is still a massive problem for you and your users if you don't fix it.

Comment: I agree with You greg, I was simply using the OP's term for the word so that the OP may comprehend the seriousness